# How to display only 1 plotchar() or label.new() instance?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Basic situation: Boolean variables get their `true` value so `plotchar()` or `label.new()` functions get triggered.

**How to display only the last one of them, deleting the previous one every time?**

Of course, a `plotchar()` should remove the previous `plotchar()` instance, and a `label.new()` removes its last label instance; no need to crosswire them. I just don't know if the solution is universal, working for both, or it's different for `plotchar()` and `label.new()` functions.

It's important that ***it should be limited to certain*** plotchar or label functions, not everything in the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot remove previous `plotchar()` instances.

You can use `label.delete()` function to remove the previous label instances. Or, better, just use the `label.set_x()` fucntion to move it to the last bar. Deleting old ones and creating new labels will reduce the performance.

```
lbl = label.new(bar_index, high, "Test")
label.delete(lbl[1])

lbl2 = label.new(bar_index, high, "Test")

if barstate.islast
    label.set_x(lbl2, bar_index)
    // Update y and text if necessary
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first create a `var` variable that is `na`. A `var` variable saves its value between bars. Then if **something happens** check if the variable is `na`, then create a `label`. This only happens one time, because right after you set the variable to the newly created `label`. If **something happens** again, just update the position.

**Code example:** where two labels mark where the latest "up" bar is and what the lastest "down" bar is.
[image: Tradingview image]

**Code:**

```
//@version=5
indicator("one label", overlay=true)

//"var" variable that gets saved between bars. First set to na
var label up = na
var label down = na

if(close > close[1])
    if(na(up)) //Does not exist, create one
        up := label.new(bar_index, close, "last up", color=color.green, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
    else
        label.set_x(up, bar_index)
    
if(close < close[1])
    if(na(down)) //Does not exist, create one
        down := label.new(bar_index, close, "last down", color=color.red, yloc=yloc.abovebar)
    else
        label.set_x(down, bar_index)
```

Comment: I'm trying to make it work. Would you please look at my new question right about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73516310/how-to-remove-the-previous-or-nth-previous-label