# How to remove the previous (or nth previous) label?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to implement an [answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73437787/2229856), but somehow no labels are displayed nor a single error message. Outside this code, all the bunch of labels are displayed so the `label.new()` instance itself works well.

What do I do wrong?

```
var label HighRSILabel = na

if(rsi > 70)
    if(na(HighRSILabel)) //Does not exist, create one
        HighRSILabel := label.new(bar_index, high, color=color.orange, text="RSI", textcolor=color.black, tooltip="RSI > 70", style=label.style_label_down)
    else
        label.set_x(HighRSILabel, bar_index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your symbol(e.g. BTCUSD) ever hit 70 rsi? Because if it never hit 70 rsi no label will be created. I tried your code with the symbol DOTEUR (1day) and it works as it should.
[image: tradingview image]

You can use tradingviews "<<Replay" function to see how the label moves through time for easier debugging.
[image: gif of playedback indicator]

Here is the code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("rsi last")

var label HighRSILabel = na

rsi = ta.rsi(close, 10)

plot(rsi)
hline(70)
hline(30)

if(rsi > 70)
    if(na(HighRSILabel)) //Does not exist, create one
        HighRSILabel := label.new(bar_index, rsi, color=color.orange, text="RSI", textcolor=color.black, tooltip="RSI > 70", style=label.style_label_down)
    else
        label.set_x(HighRSILabel, bar_index)
```

Comment: Yeah, the labels are displayed (many, under a big 3-digit limit). But by the way, I want to display them on the chart, not in the pane. I guess it's not the reason of the lack of the labels. May you please test it on the chart? I inserted your working code to mine (but the output is the chart, not a pane) and then the labels don't appear. Can't attach screenshot here.

Comment: Found it! This is a vertical positioning issue. Which I also don't understand but at least, labels are displayed, just not where I want to display them. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Btw, it's strange. If I put the label-line (with a 'high' vertical positioning) out of the IF cycle then the vertical positioning is okay. But the same line in the IF cycle puts the label up around $1900 high. Wtf…?

Comment: Here's the question for it, if you may. I'm very grateful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73517710/label-new-vertical-positioning-acts-strange-whats-wrong-how-to-fix-it