# Label.new() vertical positioning acts strange. What's wrong? How to fix it?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Here's a simple code that marks high RSI on the chart (not on a pane). With a lower 60 limit for troubleshooting.

```
indicator(title="RSI labelling", overlay=true)
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)

var label HighRSILabel = na

if(rsi > 60)
    if(na(HighRSILabel)) 
        HighRSILabel := label.new(bar_index, high, color=color.orange,  text="RSI", textcolor=color.black, tooltip="RSI > 60", style=label.style_label_down)
    else
        label.set_x(HighRSILabel, bar_index)
```

The problem is, even if it should be positioned to the `high` price value, the result is this below, see how high is that label, far above the price:
[image: Result of the code above]

**BUT if we take the `label.new()` line *out* from the `IF/ELSE` block, like this here below, then the vertical positioning gets working well:**

```
    indicator(title="RSI last", overlay=true)
    rsi = ta.rsi(close, 10)
    
    var label HighRSILabel = na
    
//    if(rsi > 60)
//        if(na(HighRSILabel)) 
//            HighRSILabel := label.new(bar_index, high, color=color.orange,  text="RSI", textcolor=color.black, tooltip="RSI > 60", style=label.style_label_down)
//        else
//            label.set_x(HighRSILabel, bar_index)
    
    HighRSILabel := label.new(bar_index, high, color=color.orange,  text="RSI", textcolor=color.black, tooltip="RSI > 60", style=label.style_label_down)
```

**Result of the non-IF/ELSE code:**
[image]
**So, to be sure, the `label.new()` line is the same in both cases. The only difference is it's inside the `IF/ELSE` block first, positioned too high, and outside the `IF/ELSE` block, positioned where it should be based on that `high` position attribute in the `label.new()` line.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also move the label's y-position in the else statement, with `label.set_y(HighRSILabel, high)`. As your code is written now it gets the y-position from the first time the label is displayed.

code that also moves the y-position:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="RSI labelling", overlay=true)
rsi = ta.rsi(close, 14)

var label HighRSILabel = na

if(rsi > 60)
    if(na(HighRSILabel)) 
        HighRSILabel := label.new(bar_index, high, color=color.orange,  text="RSI", textcolor=color.black, tooltip="RSI > 60", style=label.style_label_down)
    else
        label.set_x(HighRSILabel, bar_index)
        label.set_y(HighRSILabel, high)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if `HighRSILabel` is `na` or not. If it is `na`, you are calling the `label.new` function and assign the new id to `HighRSILabel`.

After the very first assignment, this if check will never be `true`. Beucase `HighRSILabel` will never be `na` anymore.

So, what's happening is, your else statement is getting executed and you are just moving the `x` position and not the `y`.