# How to draw only 1 a rectangle, always using the most recent data?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I can draw what I need but as new candle data arrives (e.g. every minutes in 1-min view), new rectangle appears.

I only want to draw one based on `aSeriesVariable[0]`. As it becomes `aSeriesVariable[1]`, I don't need that rectangle displayed anymore (then that becomes junk in this case).

`if barstate.last` doesn't work. Is it the same technique as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73517120/2229856)? (Which makes the indicator harder to render.) Is there any other solution that simply doesn't use any past values of the used variable?

Comment: Yes, it's the same technique you need. Have one box only, then move its position on every bar (if needed).

Comment:  Would you please consider to make it more optimized? If the cycle worked backward then the engine should not make a bunch of unnecessary calculations. :)

You know, in this case, the engine calculates the corners far back in the past, then realises to change it then again and again, and my browser&computer is lagging (just as much as we zoom out to see more past candles). It should work backward, form the present towards the past, I guess. For the labels, too, of course. Same logics.

Comment: The code on your link is quite optimal, there are no complicated calculations, and even more so, references far back in the past (which will not affect rendering lags in any way).
There may be problems in your rectangle rendering code or in your hardware.

Comment: @vitruvius , I found a workaround, acceptable, sort of. If I add a barstate.islast to the criterion then the first bar it starts the calculations from is the bar when I loaded the chart with these indicators using this code. Lagging is gone, for a long while, even if I zoom out to see a long array of candles and the related indicator plots and labels etc. If I remove this criteria then the lag starts immediately, after zooming out.

Comment: @vgladkov, It's a Mac Pro. In Activity Monitor (ALL Processes displayed), there's no significant CPU/GPU load or RAM Load or Stress btw.  I'll try to test it on a PC though.

As I understood it, maybe I'm not wrong; it goes back to the very first bar displayed and looks if the label/box exists. It doesn't so it creates, then in the next time it culls the previous label/box by modifying it. The more series of bars are displayed, the more labels/boxes become culled, and every single labels/boxes culled was unnecessary to give a single bit to calculate or include into the IF cycle.

Comment: All these calculations take place on the platform servers, so they cannot affect rendering lags on your computer in any way.
I think you should report this to the support team, because in terms of the code being discussed there are no optimization problems

Comment: @vgladkov Wow, it's interesting. :) Then please try to make a quick theoretical troubleshooting. My Mac is on brutal lag, even a minimal Twitter video played on 2-3 fps, even the mouse pointer is lagging. Five TradingView tabs opened btw, in separate browser window. Then I simply closed this window, thus all the TV charts dropped. Machine immediately returned to the usual smooth operation. Not a 360p but 4K Youtube video replay becomes smooth. Immediately. Why?